# json, trying to access array

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Im trying to access the email part of the json string

{"email":"Please enter a valide email address","pass":"Please enter your password"}"

Its pass to a function like so

```
postActor: function(){
    var self = checkLogin;
        $.ajax({
        data: self.config.form.serialize(),
            success: function(results) {
            if(results){
                        console.log({results: email});      
            alert('this should worlk');
                } else {
                                   alert('this isn't working');
                }
            }
        });
    },
```

Its driving me crazy can someone point out what im doing wrong.
Thanx

Answer (score 1):

`{results: email}` would be object literal syntax to create an object.  You need to use either `results.email` or `results['email']`.

EDIT: based on what @TravisJ said, you might need to parse the results.  It's unlikely, but your options include:

1. Setting the `application/json` as the `Content-type` header when the JSON is emitted
2. Using `dataType: json` as one of the `$.ajax` arguments
3. Using `$.parseJSON` or `JSON.parse` on the string `results`.

Comment: Depending on how it is sent, it may also need to be parsed as json.

Answer (score 0):

Access the property using dot notation, `results.email`

```
postActor: function(){
    var self = checkLogin;
        $.ajax({
        data: self.config.form.serialize(),
            success: function(results) {
                if(results){
                    console.log(results.email);      
                    alert('this should worlk');
                } else {
                    alert('this isn't working');
                }
            }
        });
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the results variable is a json encoded string, you would have to parse it as json.  Either with JSON.parse(string), or if the dataType json is specified.. just use object access notation:

```
results.email
```

or

```
results['email'].
```

JSON is **J**ava**s**cript **O**bject **N**otation, and you can read more info about it here: http://www.json.org/

Aside from that, you forgot to escape your quote mark in the following line:

```
alert('this isn't working');
           //  ^ this should be escaped.
```

This is likely causing the rest of your function to break.